# Why isn't the image displaying in the client browser when sent via a socket write?

Tags: java, sockets, maven

I am creating a simple HTTP server (with maven).  When the user enters `http://127.0.0.1:8181/pic`, an image should be displayed.

When I run the class and enter `http://127.0.0.1:8181/pic`, the image doesn't display; I just get lines of garbage characters instead!

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int port = 8181;

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("Listening for a connection on port " + port + " ...");

    while (true) {
        Socket client = server.accept();
        System.out.println("A client connected: " + client.getInetAddress());

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));

        String line = in.readLine();
        while (!line.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(line);

            String[] firstLine = line.split("\\s+"); // line is like: GET /pic HTTP/1.1
            String method = firstLine[0];

            if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {

                String resourceNme = firstLine[1];

                if (resourceNme.equals("/pic")) {

                    out.write("Server: Apache/0.8.4\r\n");
                    out.write("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
                    out.write("Content-type: image/gif");

                    out.write("\r\n");
                    out.write("<TITLE>Example Image</TITLE>");

                    //find file in system and send as response
                    URL url = SimpleHTTPServer.class.getResource("/office.jpg");
                    File file = new File(url.toURI());

                    if (file.exists()) {
                        System.out.println("file exists");
                        ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
                        long size = imageInputStream.length();

                        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
                        boolean success = ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", client.getOutputStream());
                        System.out.println("Success: " + success); // is true
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("don't exists");
                    }

                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    client.close();
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample output received:**

```
SHùiÆƒ@8¤ÇîÔéHŽ”c­;… äúÑ“ëIŠ1@ËQ“ï@¥Å��œ÷¥Éõ¢Š�9õ¥Éõ¤¥ 'Ö€ÄzÑF(wzFb;ÑPÈø¤d”Œòj³HÄõ4®ù¨è»›ûÆÍýãIE�.æþñ£sxÒb—�noï7·÷£�ííêi|Æþñ¦âœ�Û?xÒïoïLRâ€
íýãNÞßÞ4ÜRâ€{xÑ½¿¼i1F)�»›ûÆÍýãE�noSFæõ4bŒPîoïPíýãH ooï77÷ ¸ ÙûÆ—sxÓ@æ—�»›ûÆ—-ëMÅ--ýãFæõ4QŠ�]ÍêiK6:ÒRã4Ä"ï,�'šé4]5‹od•Ÿ§é­1G*H<×saf©œ`ŽÕ¤DÉ µÅXÆÓš~=iÈÅjf0¯9 ¨àŠv21@ 2äç¸ÈÎ)øãÆ)€ÜdRàÆ)zR‚E �7-�”v P�(�r)hÆ
0œbŒu¥ÆiHç4�˜”`n¥Åw Ú3JGJZ"€G|R°Î)våhÆåÅ�>ZR2™ |Ê>”ª3=)0
£f=©/ð§'+BŒ(c�¸¸Åâ€Œ
```

**Updated Code with HTML-related response codes removed**

```
                if (resourceNme.equals("/pic")) {
                    out.write("Server: Apache/0.8.4\r\n");
                    out.write("Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n");

                    URL url = SimpleHTTPServer.class.getResource("/office.jpg");
                    File file = new File(url.toURI());

                    if (file.exists()) {
                        System.out.println("file exists");
                        ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
                        long size = imageInputStream.length();
                        out.write("Content-Length: " + size + "\r\n");
                        out.write("\r\n");

                        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
                        boolean success = ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", client.getOutputStream());
                        System.out.println("Success: " + success); //true
                        out.close();
                        in.close();
                        client.close();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("don't exists");
                        out.close();
                        in.close();
                        client.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: try changing your page encoding. It's probably displaying an error message.

Comment: @DanielCheung It's in `unicode`, change it to what?

Comment: Anything else and try to see if you can understand anything with a different encoding to check whether or not this **is really** rubbish text.

Comment: @DanielCheung Not worked

Comment: Well then, you'll have to wait for another one to help, good luck

Comment: @DanielCheung Ok, thanks for your attention.

Comment: @youtubefreak Whats your mean? my image is in resource folder of maven, and it's correctly loaded.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but is your image file extension actually .jpeg and have you tried using .jpg?

Comment: I'm not a HTTP expert, but I think what's causing this is the fact that you're sending text after \r\n, but you should only send the binary data of the picture. Try removing the <TITLE> line, the , and add a content-length header. And why do you have 2 content-type headers? How is the browser supposed to know which is the right one?

Comment: My image extension is `.jpg` which i should write as `jpeg` in code, i tried all possible items, such as `.jpeg` , `.jpg` , `jpeg` and `jpg`, and not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending both text and the binary data of the picture directly behind each other. How is the browser supposed to know how to separate the two? If you want to combine HTML and an image, you should have a a href=... element in your HTML. If you only want to send the picture, set the content type to image/jpeg, but you cannot have two content types at the same time. Remove your first content-type line, remove the line with TITLE in it. Change the URL under which you want to be able to call the image to pic.jpg and it should work.